# How do I create a prototype function that binds another prototype function as syntactic sugar (and keep the context of the instance)?

Tags: javascript, prototype, syntactic-sugar

I have declared a prototype function `A.a` but would like to provide some syntactic sugar by other functions, e.g. `A.sayHi` and `A.sayBye`. The problem is binding the context because of course I'd like it to point to the instance but don't have access to it when I declare the prototype.

```
function A() {
    this.txt = 'so';
};

A.prototype.a = function (txt) {
    alert(txt + ' ' + this.txt);
}

A.prototype.sayHi = A.prototype.a.bind(A, 'hi');

A.prototype.sayBye = A.protoype.a.bind(A.prototype, 'bye');
```

When I do `new A().sayHi().sayBye();` I get alerts with "hi undefined" and "bye undefined". Sure, I can do

```
A.prototype.sayHi = function() {
    this.a('hi');
};
```

but that's ugly :)

Is there a way that I keep the context of the instance (so that `this.txt` equals 'so') without writing a function?

Comment: You won't be able to do this. The problem is because your `bind` code is being ran before any instance is created, hence you will never be able to pass the correct `this` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind is not what you want.

Bind is designed to create a function that wraps a `this` pointer (which must exist when Bind is called), to avoid having to write lots of temporary functions like

```
var that = this;
callMeBack(function() { that.callback(); });
```

(i.e. the above becomes)

```
callMeBack(this.callback.Bind(this));
```

It can be used for partial application / limited currying, but in your case you don't have a `this` at the point you're trying to call Bind. You definitely don't want either the constructor or its prototype object to be `this`, you want this to be the actual object, but that doesn't exist when you run this code.

Your last example is exactly right.

---

Digression: I don't think it is ugly - it is clear, and explicit, and highly idiomatic Javascript. Perhaps a touch verbose. If you think this is ugly, then you may not be used to Javascript yet. Get used to functions as first-class data, e.g.:

```
var A = function() { ... };
```

instead of

```
function A { ... }
```

the former being what Javascript means by the latter. Getting into the habit of thinking of functions as just another data-type, will help you 'get' Javascript and see its inherent beauty. And will have the side-effect that you won't be offended by the 'ugly' on show when you program for node.js :)

Comment: That's been my thinking exactly, bind doesn't work because it only works on instances. I wanted to curry A.a by creating A.sayHi, but I guess that's not possible without having access to the context (i.e. by creating a function that wraps it).

Comment: @godspeedelbow Well, because you can create and return functions at will, if you want a function that currys for prototypes, and applies the correct pointer at runtime, when it is available, you can write that. Shreyas gives an example of doing that. There's very little point for just one or two uses, however, you may as well use the 'ugly' approach. But it does nicely illustrate how powerful local functions and lexical typing are.

Comment: Shreyas answer doesn't really guarantee that `this` has the right value, it's a more complicated looking answer than the one Grundy gave. You can only guarantee value of `this` when passing the function as a closure/use bind or declaring the function in the constructor body (me=this;this.sayHi=function(){me.a("Hi")}).

Comment: @HMR - I think you're mistaking what I / Shreyas am suggesting. The behavior you suggest is the behavior of Bind, but the point is Bind is not the right tool for the OP's job. The OP gave an example of what he/she wanted, but thought it was 'ugly' and was trying to use Bind to make it more beautiful. Bind was not the right tool for that job, and your code wouldn't work either.

Comment: Although a couple of interesting work arounds given, it's indeed clear that it's not possible. I'll accept your answer, thanks!

As a side note, the reason I think it's 'ugly' is because unnecessarily adding function wrappers instead of binding creates boilerplate. I was hoping there might be a way to do this elegantly on the prototype with something else than `bind` but alas. Now I'll happily write those function bodies.

Comment: @godspeedelbow Thanks! I get what you mean by the boilerplate, sorry if I came over snooty in my first reply. But by the time you've typed `Constructor.prototype.method.bind(` you've typed more than `function() { this.method(` anyway :) It would be nice if Javascript had a lightweight function definition operator like Rust's |x| {...} or OCaml's ->

Answer (score 1):

you can try little change `a` function

```
function A() {
    this.txt = 'so';
};

A.prototype.a = function (txt) {
    return function(){
        alert(txt + ' ' + this.txt);
        return this;
    }
}

A.prototype.sayHi = A.prototype.a("Hi")

A.prototype.sayBye = A.protoype.a('bye');
```

Comment: Cool answer! So effectively, we disable `A.a` a little bit so that we can curry it :) The downside is that `A.a` behaves differently now, so that you'd almost want only available as a private function.

Comment: Nice. You'd still need another function if you want to have the generic version too, unless you're happy to write foo.a("Hola")();

Comment: This doesn't really bind the functions to an instance though: `var a = new A();
var b = {};
b.sayHi = a.sayHi;
b.sayHi();` this.txt is undefined now.

Comment: @HMR - that's exactly what I'd expect it to. The point of what godspeedelbow seemed to be doing was to form a partial application on a prototype method, not bind a this pointer, which is exactly why Bind was not the right tool. If you really did want to bind the this pointer, then you'd have to do something else, but since the OP didn't even have an object created, I assumed this was not needed. And it seems like the asker agrees. If you want to create a new question with an example of when you'd need to do what you're saying here, we can try to give a clearer answer.

Comment: @HMR yep, because there is no `txt` field in `b`

Comment: The object b and wether or not it has txt member wouldn't matter when you bind it: `b.sayHi=a.sayHi.bind(a);` or when you pass a closure. I may have misunderstood the OP wanting to bind because of this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
function runtimeContextBinder(func){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
 return function(){
   func.apply(this,args);
 }
}

function A() {
    this.txt = 'so';
};

A.prototype.a = function (txt) {
    alert(txt + ' ' + this.txt);
}

A.prototype.sayHi = runtimeContextBinder(A.prototype.a,'hi');

A.prototype.sayBye = runtimeContextBinder(A.prototype.a, 'bye');
```

What I'm doing here is to create a closure on the function, which is then executed in the context of the instance.

Comment: You're generating elbow's 'ugly' local function from within another function :) Nicely meta.

Comment: Yeah, that would work but as Ian said, you're creating a closure in `runtimeContextBinder` which effectively does the same as writing a function, but then only once. Thanks anyways though!

Comment: @Ian So what is `Function.prototype.bind` doing internally?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Basically what I showed in my answer, it is fixing 'this' by using a closure, it will then use `apply` to feed in the argument list. Looks like Shreyas is about to give a definition, there's a full one at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: `Function.prototype.bind = function(context){
    var thisFunction = this;
    return function(){
    thisFunction.apply(context,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
    }`

Comment: @Shreyas - neat, the zero should be 1 though (get rid of the 'this' pointer).

Comment: @Shreyas - I don't think you can do multiline in comments, :(. Nice one-liner then ;)

Comment: @Ian If you take a look at [ES5 §15.3.4.5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5), looking at #4 You see that a "closure" is created as well. There is no approach on what the OP is trying to do without using closures.

Comment: @Ian it should be 0. Else you'll lose out the first argument. `this` pointer is not present in the arguments.

Comment: @Shreyas theres a tiny little [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) link with some hints on comment formatting, when you're adding a comment

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 I didn't mean to suggest there was. Sorry if I gave that impression. The OP wanted to avoid his explicit inline function. Shreyas's solution was just to wrap making that function into its own function, to avoid the 'ugly'. You asked what Bind does, and I said it creates a closure, and gave a link to the implementation that does that. So I don't think I was being misleading. If so, then it wasn't intentional.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 - oh i see, you thought I was sayng that Shreyas's function generator was doing things that Bind woudln't have to? Got ya. No, I wasn't saying that. I was responding to the fact that Shreyas's solution would mean that the OP would have to write his 'ugly' in his code anyway, but just inside another function. Better to just come to terms with local function definitions in the first place, imho. Though, if he's got tens of partial applications to wrap, Shreyas's solution is clearly better.

Comment: @Shreyas, right, sorry. Confused me because Bind also passes through the arguments *it* gets (except the first). To which, the arguments its closure receives are appended, I misread which argument list you were adjusting at that point.

Comment: @Ian Yup, that's what I thought :) Thanks for clearing things up :)